# Sincronizar dois bancos MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e gostaria de colocar o sistema funcionando tanto *online*, quanto *offline*. A ideia é manter um banco de dados local que responda quando o usuário estiver *offline*, mas não sei como posso fazer para sincronizar os dados entre o banco local e o remoto quando a conexão é restabelecida.

Sei como ver se o computador está ou não com internet, só não sei como atualizar os dados após ele estar com internet.

Comment: Você deve logo que a conexão for estabelecida fazer uma HTTP request para o servidor enviando os dados locais e inserindo/atualizando no banco de dados. Não tem muito segredo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve trabalhar com o MySql Replication, que consiste um 1 banco de dados mestre onde são feitas as inclusões e vários bancos escravos para leitura. Este mecanismo é interessante para load balance, integridade dos dados e performance.

Visão geral da ferramenta.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

Aqui tem os direcionamentos para realizar as configurações:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-configuration.html

**Não deixe de ler cuidadosamente os links que te passei, atentando-se a versão do seu MySql**